# Eigenvector Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix $X$, let $eigvec(X)$ be its eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue.

Is there a relationship among $eigvec(X+X^T)$, $eigvec(X)$ and $eigvec(X^T)$? In other words,
can I use the results of $eigvec(X)$ and $eigvec(X^T)$ to obtain $eigvec(X+X^T)$ ?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $X$?  Symmetry? Normality?

Comment: I don't think there's much that can be done with this in general.

Comment: $X$ is a matrix with all positive elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I don't think so.

Suppose, for example, that $A$ is a symmetric matrix with all diagonal entries equal to 0 (like the adjacency matrix of a simple, loopless graph), and let $X$ be the upper triangular matrix such that $A=X+X^T$.  Then the only eigenvalue of $X$ will be 0, and likewise for $X^T$. The first standard basis vector is an eigenvector of $X$ for 0 and the $n$th standard basis vector is an eigenvector of $X^T$ for 0 (these are the only guaranteed eigenvectors of $X$ and $X^T$ for the eigenvalue 0, respectively, though there could be more).

The matrix $A$, on the other hand, could have many nonzero eigenvalues, and the corresponding eigenvectors need not be related in a simple way to the standard unit vectors.  You can generate some random symmetric matrices and see for yourself.